# connecting Android to Oracle

Tags: android

I'm new and am trying to connect an android application to my oracle db. My current code is throwing the error:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException ...

My connection code is as follows:

```
public class ConnectOra {

    public String driver, url, ip, bd, usr, pass;
    public Connection conexion;

    public ConnectOra(String ip, String bd, String usr, String pass) {

        driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        this.bd = bd;
        this.usr = usr;
        this.pass = pass;
        url = new String("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + ip + ":1521:" + bd);

        try {

            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, pass);

            // revisan el log para ver que tira....
            System.out.println("Conexion a Base de Datos " + bd + " Exitosa");
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println("Error al tratar de abrir la base de Datos "
                                 + bd + " : " + exc + "ricardo");

        }
}

public Connection getConexion() {
    return conexion;
}

public Connection CerrarConexion() throws SQLException {
    conexion.close();
    conexion = null;
    return conexion;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well as the error suggests, you cannot do a network connection on the main thread... So put it in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use another thread for network tasks.

I recommend you use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

U should implement AsyncTask and add:   to your android mainfest.

Anyway, it's a really bad practice in termns of security made a direct connection from any local client to a remote DB, that model extinguished for very good reasons years ago, in this case, in Android, if u have the apk file, u can decompress it and then decompile the java source files for get the db credentials and gain complete access to the db.